# CSS Menu Not Working on Mobiles or Tablets

Tags: html, angularjs, css, viewport

I have created the plunkr found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gqtFoQ4x2ONnn1BfRmI9?p=preview

This menu works as expected on a desktop/laptop.. But it does not look as it does on a desktop.

I imagine the CSS is correct, but something wrong with the viewport settings??

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-style="{true: {overflow: 'hidden'}, false: {}}[toggleMenu]">

  <div class="header compact" role="banner">
    <div class="menu" ng-class="{true: 'active', false: ' '}[toggleMenu]" ng-style="{true: {width: menuWidth}, false: {}}[toggleMenu]">
      <h2 ng-click="toggleMenu = true">Menu</h2>
      <div class="nav" ng-style="{ 'width' : winWidth, 'height' : winHeight }">
        <ul role="navigation" class="nav-main">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="../makani/" data-ga-event="Header,Navigate,Home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="../makani/challenge/" data-ga-event="Header,Navigate,The Challenge">The
              Challenge</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul role="contentinfo" class="nav-aux">
          <li>
            <a href="../makani/faq/" data-ga-event="Footer,Navigate,FAQ">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="../makani/about/" data-ga-event="Footer,Navigate,About Us">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button type="button" ng-click="toggleMenu = false">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't see anything in your plnkr. It's very likely going to be the CSS. We'd need to see that. If you think it's the viewport then you can try replacing with this instead, I've used it a lot on commercial projects and it's always been fine. 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: just replace this div "<div class="nav" ng-style="{ 'width' : winWidth, 'height' : winHeight }">" to "<div class="nav">"

Comment: @Amit - do you have an updated plunkr?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ws7A9r7aJgd1SUvXBbmc?p=preview

Comment: @Amit - the menu is supposed to consume the entire width of the page. Go here on your mobile: http://www.google.com/makani/ you can see workign example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using any vendor prefixes in your css. Even iOS 8 requires them to be present. So in addition to `transform` also `-webkit-transform`.

See http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

BTW: Nice menu.

Comment: are you sure? Im using the same CSS found here: http://www.google.com/makani/ and there are no webkit references. (resize your browser to view)

Comment: Are you talking about that css: http://www.google.com/makani/css/default.css There are a lot of vendor-prefixes.

Comment: Solved, prefixes was the issue.!